# Razor: how to use variables defined in page templates

Tags: razormediator

I'm using Razor templates and I've defined a variable in the page templates. How can I used the variable in the component template using razor?

In my Razor template I have:

```
@{
    string hotelTCM = @Package.Hotel_ID;
}
```

How can I use it in a embbeded component template?

Comment: Are you talking about a variable defined in your Razor template? Something on the package? A metadata field...? Clarify your question.

Comment: Please update your question with your code, screenshots, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package variables (and the package instance) are independent to the Template item, meaning a package variable from a Page Template will not be available to a Component Template, since the latter has its own package instance.

If you want to pass variables between Templates (Page -> Component) you can use a `ContextVariable`, see also https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/PassContextFromOneComponentRenderToAnother

```cs
// in your Page Template
...
engine.PublishingContext.RenderContext.ContextVariables.Add("contextBag", contextBag);
```

and

```cs
// in your Component Template
...
var contextBag = (Dictionary<string, object>)engine.PublishingContext.RenderContext.ContextVariables["contextBag"];
```

### update

I have to add, this is the case for the [Modular Templating Framework](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-6FF6827A-5B80-4C05-981B-9D2F11473BE5) using DWT TBBs, I'm not a 100% sure this also counts for the [Razor Mediator](https://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/) which you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it by writing the following in your template.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty()) {
    <p>@hotelTCM</p>
}
```

More information is in the documentation;

```
@{
    int x = 123;
    bool test = true;
    string y = "because.";
    var greeting = "Hello";
}

<div>@greeting</div>
<div>@(test ? y : greeting)</div>
```

Comment: This works if I use the variable in the same page template. But If I try to use it in a embbeded component template doesn't work. Actually, I can save the razor component template because it doesn't interpret @*hotelTCM. I've tried @*Package.Hotel_ID and didn't work...

Comment: Please provide more information about what you want to achieve what you have and have done